# Make an IObservable subscription concurrent

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive, rx.net

I have the following code

```
string dataDirectory = _settingsProvider.DataSettings.BaseDirectory;
_solverManagementService.MergedPointCloudProducer(dataDirectory, cancellationToken)
    .Subscribe(PointCloudMergerCompleted);
```

where the `SolverManagementService _solverManagementService` is

```
Public class SolverManagementService : ISolverManagementService
{
    public IObservable<IPointCloud> MergedPointCloudProducer(string dataDirectory,
        CancellationToken token)
    {
        return Observable.Create<IPointCloud>(
            observer =>
            {
                PairCollectionProducer(dataDirectory, token)
                    .Subscribe(pairCollection =>
                    {
                        observer.OnNext(_icpBatchSolverService.RecursivelyMergeAsync(
                            pairCollection, token));
                    },
                    onCompleted: () =>
                    {
                        observer.OnCompleted();
                    });
                return () => { };
            });
    }
    ... // Other methods. 
}
```

But here `_icpBatchSolverService.RecursivelyMergeAsync(pairCollection, token)` is expensive and although this returns a `Task<IPointCloud>` I do not threadify this and this call blocks. As `RecursivelyMergeAsync` returns a `Task<IPointCloud>` it can be awaited, so I have amended the code to use `async/await`

```
public IObservable<IPointCloud> MergedPointCloudProducer(string dataDirectory,
    CancellationToken token)
{
    return Observable.Create<IPointCloud>(
        observer =>
        {
            PairCollectionProducer(dataDirectory, token)
                .Subscribe(async (pairCollection) =>
                {
                    observer.OnNext(await _icpBatchSolverService.RecursivelyMergeAsync(
                        pairCollection, token));
                },
                onCompleted: () =>
                {
                    observer.OnCompleted();
                });
            return () => { };
        });
}
```

but now it returns immediately and the console app shuts down. I am sure this can be done without the need for `Semephores`, but I am new to RX. How can I configure the `RecursivelyMergeAsync` to be run concurrently for each returned `pairCollection` without blocking and getting a notification when all recursive merges complete?

*Note. In a unit test, I do the following*

```
public class IcpBatchSolverServiceTests
{
    private Mock<ISettingsProvider> _mockSettingsProvider; 
    private IIcpBatchSolverService _icpBatchSolverService;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _mockSettingsProvider = new Mock<ISettingsProvider>();

        _mockSettingsProvider.Setup(m => m.IcpSolverSettings).Returns(new IcpSolverSettings());
        _mockSettingsProvider.Object.IcpSolverSettings.MaximumDegreeOfParallelism = 6;

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();

        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddLogging(builder =>
            {
                builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
                builder.AddSerilog(Log.Logger);
            })
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        ILogger<IcpBatchSolverServiceTests> logger = serviceProvider
            .GetService<ILoggerFactory>()
            .CreateLogger<IcpBatchSolverServiceTests>();

        _icpBatchSolverService = new IcpBatchSolverService(_mockSettingsProvider.Object, logger);
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task CanSolveBatchAsync()
    {
        IPointCloud @static = PointCloudFactory.GetRandomPointCloud(1000);
        List<IPointCloud> pointCloudList = PointCloudFactory.GenerateRandomlyRotatedBatch(@static, 12);

        IPartitioningService<IPointCloud> ps = new PointCloudPartitioningService();
        IPointCloud result = await _icpBatchSolverService.RecursivelyMergeAsync(ps.Partition(pointCloudList), CancellationToken.None);

        Assert.AreEqual(@static.Vertices.Length, result.Vertices.Length);
    }
}
```

*And this processes concurrently perfectly.*

---

*Edit. Outline of what processing I need to do when provided a folder of files for different geometries (depth maps for different geometries at different angles) with naming convention .NNNN.exr where NNNN is some numeric value. For a batch of files.*

1. *Batch these files into collections using file name for the different geometries.*

*foreach file batch*

1. *[*Serial*] Call C++ API to extract DepthMaps from image files.*
2. *[*Parallel*] Convert `DepthMaps` to `PointClouds`. this can be done all at once.*
3. *[*Parallel*] Merge PointClouds using ICP algorithm (expensive) but limit concurrency with `TaskScheduler` to two threads (chosen depending on machine architecture/memory etc.)*

*At the end of this I make another call to C++ API with the merged point cloud from step 3. So in RX my current full pipeline looks like*

```
public class SolverManagementService : ISolverManagementService
{
    private readonly IIcpBatchSolverService _icpBatchSolverService;
    private readonly IDepthMapToPointCloudAdapter _pointCloudAdapter;
    private readonly ILogger<SolverManagementService> _logger;

    public SolverManagementService(
        IIcpBatchSolverService icpBatchSolverService,
        IDepthMapToPointCloudAdapter pointCloudAdapter,
        ILogger<SolverManagementService> logger)
    {
        _icpBatchSolverService = icpBatchSolverService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("icpBatchSolverService cannot be null");
        _pointCloudAdapter = pointCloudAdapter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("pointCloudAdapter cannot be null");
        _logger = logger; 
    }

    public IObservable<IPointCloud> MergedPointCloudProducer(string dataDirectory, CancellationToken token)
    {
        return Observable.Create<IPointCloud>(
            observer =>
            {
                PairCollectionProducer(dataDirectory, token)
                    .Subscribe(pairCollection =>
                    {
                        observer.OnNext(_icpBatchSolverService.RecursivelyMergeAsync(pairCollection, token).Result);
                    },
                    onCompleted: () =>
                    {
                        observer.OnCompleted();
                    });
                return () => { };
            });
    }

    public IObservable<PairCollection<IPointCloud>> PairCollectionProducer(string dataDirectory, CancellationToken token)
    {
        return Observable.Create<PairCollection<IPointCloud>>(
            observer =>
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(
                    Utils.GetFileBatches(dataDirectory), 
                    (fileBatch) =>
                {
                    var producer = RawDepthMapProducer(fileBatch, token);
                    ConcurrentBag<IPointCloud> bag = new ConcurrentBag<IPointCloud>();

                    producer.Subscribe(rawDepthMap =>
                    {
                        bag.Add(_pointCloudAdapter.GetPointCloudFromDepthMap(rawDepthMap));
                        _logger?.LogDebug($"Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}: {bag.Count:N0} PointCloud(s) added to concurrent bag");
                    }, 
                    onCompleted: () =>
                    {
                        PointCloudPartitioningService ps = new PointCloudPartitioningService();
                        observer.OnNext(ps.Partition(bag.ToList()));

                        _logger?.LogDebug($"Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}: PointCloud PairCollection generated " +
                            $"for file set \"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(bag.FirstOrDefault().Source)}\"");
                    });
                });
                observer.OnCompleted();
                return () => { };
            });
    }

    public IObservable<RawDepthMap> RawDepthMapProducer(List<string> filePaths, CancellationToken token)
    {
        return Observable.Create<RawDepthMap>(
            observer =>
            {
                int index = 0;
                foreach(var filePath in filePaths)
                {
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    var extractor = DepthMapExtractorFactory.GetDepthMapExtractor(filePath);

                    observer.OnNext(extractor.GetDepthMap(filePath, index++));
                    _logger?.LogDebug($"Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}: DepthMap extracted from \"{filePath}\"");
                }
                observer.OnCompleted();
                return () => { };
            });
    }
}
```

*I am seeking: 1. What is wrong with my code above note `_icpBatchSolverService.RecursivelyMergeAsync` returns a `Task<IPointCloud` and is concurrent and I would like this tow run concurrently. 2. What else is wrong with my code?*

Comment: You shouldn’t call subscribe in the create method.

Comment: I am chaining `IObservable` feeds. My `PairCollectionProducer` is also and `IObservable`.

Comment: You're also mixing async and await with observable, which is a big no-no - case in point here as to why. If you clean that up, the problem will no doubt become clear.

Comment: I think that the problem is that the generated `IObservable` is completed before all async operations are completed. You may need to defer the `observer.OnCompleted()` call.

Comment: @MoonKnight - Your main problem here is that you're calling `OnNext` inside a `Subscribe`. That's a recipe for disaster. Also the overuse of `Observable.Create` makes your life hard. I would really need to get a [mcve] from you to be able to sort this all out, but I suspect that you can do what you need with a few pure RX queries. Can you provide me full, compilable code to look at?

Comment: Thanks very much for the offer, but I have decided to go away from RX. I have coded this up using the TPL and it works fabulously. I think although this _might_ be doable with RX, it is not the right tool for what I want to do here.

Comment: @MoonKnight - Usually when TPL does the job then Rx can do it more succinctly. It's often worth persevering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to leave a generic answer, because the code up above is too extensive to boil it down.

There are two syntaxes which may be used to define asynchronous behavior. The first is the `async/await` pattern and the second, and older, is the `Subscribe()` pattern (reactive).

**Is asynchronous the same thing as concurrent?**

No, it is definitely not.  For those who might be reading this who don't know, asynchronous means "it happens later," not "it happens concurrently." By using either of these syntaxes, you're defining behavior that happens immediately after some predicate has been met. A very common use case is to handle a response coming back from a web server. You need to make the request, then do something when the response comes back.

Concurrency is different. You might invoke concurrency by using `Task.Run()` or `Parallel.ForEach()`, for example. In both cases, you're defining a fork. In the case of `Task.Run`, you might then later do a `Task.WaitAll`. In the case of the `Parallel.ForEach`, it will do the fork/join for you.  Of course, reactive has its own set of fork/join operations.

**What happens when I await or subscribe?**

The following two lines of code both have the same behavior, and that behavior confuses a good number of programmers:

`var result = await myAsync();`

`myObservable.Subscribe(result => { ... });`

In both cases, the control flow of the program moves in a predictable, but potentially-confusing fashion. In the first case, control flow returns back to the parent caller while the `await` is being awaited. In the second, control flow moves on to the next line of code, with the lambda expression being called upon the return of the result.

A common thing that I've seen among people learning how to use these is to try to assign a variable from within the lambda to an address in the parent scope. This isn't going to work, because that scope will cease to exist long before the lambda is executed.  It's less likely to do something stupid using `async/await`, but you also have to remember that the control flow will go up the call stack until the next synchronous operation is defined. [This article explains it in a little more depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/control-flow-in-async-programs), and [this article](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/understand-control-flow-async-await) is a little easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for this. I clearly need to read more about Reactive to get the concurrency I required without mixing mantras. I don’t actually like the way one has to chain operations using RX, so I might chop it out and write this again without RX. Thought I’d use it as a learning exercise, but I have much to learn it seems. Thanks very much for your time here, it is most appreciated.

Comment: @MoonKnight- I actually think your situation calls for Rx. The chaining works very similar to how LINQ chaining works. It’s used to transform one observable into another. The subscribe function is then called at the end to start the whole thing going. You generally don’t need to use Observable.create either- your first observable comes form whatever you’re making a call to.

Comment: I thought so too, but I could write the concurrent code I need so easily and RX seems to be bogging me down here due to lack of knowledge (perhaps I should invest to learn what I need) and the complexity of what I need. I have updated the question, if you could provide any explicit examples of how I could tweak what I have to do what I want, I’d happily provide a bounty of your choice.

Comment: Well, Rx really isn't a *concurrent* framework, it's an *asynchronous* framework that happens to support a limited degree of concurrency. Take a look at [Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl).

Comment: Yeah, I think I’m best to step away from it here. Again, thanks for taking time to help me. Most appreciated.