# If you kill the thread that started a `async` task, do you kill the task?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library

One of the pitfalls of `async` method is that the operation can be executed on different threads. This can be verified by:

```
var z = 0;
while (z < 20)
{
   Console.Write(" - Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
   await Task.Delay(1000);
   z++;
}
```

which will output something like:
`- Thread: 1 - Thread: 1 - Thread: 4 - Thread: 6 - Thread: 7 - Thread: 4`

On a regular approach, if you use:

```
var z = 0;
while (z < 20)
{
   Console.Write(" - Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
   z++;
}
```

your output will be:
`- Thread: 1 - Thread: 1 - Thread: 1 - Thread: 1 - Thread: 1 - Thread: 1`

Now, if you encapsulate the first code on a `Thread` like this:

```
var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(async () =>
{
    var z = 0;
    while (z < 20)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        z++;
    }
}));
thread.Start();
```

if you `thread.Abort` will you reliably kill the `async` operation running?

Comment: Pretty much everything after thread abort is undefined behavior; don't do that!

Comment: Tasks or threads, if you want to be able to "cancel", you should use a CancellationToken to signal the threads to stop working, and as @Fabjan said "Mixing threads with async code 'smells' and is not recommended"

Comment: There is nothing reliable about Thread.Abort().  That raises an exception on the thread.  Many things can happen ... consider try-catch-finally blocks, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The idea of a async method is that the operation can be executed on different threads.

No. The idea of an `async` method is a method that can be paused while another operation is going on and then can be resumed later. Some `async` methods can resume on different threads; others cannot.

> if you thread.Abort will you reliably kill the async operation running?

No. As soon as the method hits the first `await`, the thread will exit. If the `Thread.Abort` runs before the thread gets to the `await`, the code will be aborted. If the `Thread.Abort` runs after the thread does the `await`, the thread will already be exiting.

Answer (score 2):

> The idea of a async method is that the operation can be executed on
>   different threads.

The idea of an async method is that the operation needs to be executed asynchronously and *not necessarily* on a separate thread. Some I/O operations do not require thread-pool threads and are executed on I/O threads instead.

Here are a few considerations that I would consider:

- The keyword `await` creates a state machine that handles the async operation and it's continuation.
- Mixing threads with `async` code 'smells' and is not recommended.
- Technically, if the async operation is executing on a thread-pool thread aborting the thread in which it started won't kill the operation, however most likely, it means that you don't care how the `async` operation ends, and you won't be able to handle it if it is in faulty state.
- The `Thread.Abort` method is not supported in `.Net Core` and if you run it you'll see:

  "Unhandled exception. System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Thread abort is not supported on this platform"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried stepping through this code with the debugger? I think that what you'll find is that, since nothing is awaiting the `async` inside of the `ThreadStart` that the thread is done immediately as soon as it encounters the first `await`, and the loop will be terminated.

Why? Because `async/await` was not designed to *execute a method on multiple threads*. The fact that it can do so is a by-product of its purpose.

It was designed to allow, at some point further down the call stack, for a thread to do other things (like listen to the UI inputs) while the asynchronous portion of the work is continuing. The behavior of `await` is to return control to the parent caller. Since there is no parent caller, the thread terminates upon `await`.

You may be interested in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59743240/make-an-iobservable-subscription-concurrent/59743968#59743968), where this is explained in a bit more detail.